# Build flutter app for desktops

Tags: dart, flutter

I saw a few peoples managed to build flutter apps for other OS than the usual Android/IOS

My question here is simple : How ? What is the current process to build a flutter app for mac/windows ? There's no need for it to be *production ready*. Something experimental is enough

Comment: It's currently definitely not officially supported. Hixie posted a link in Gitter for build instructions the last 3 weeks or so as far as I know. It shouldn't be too hard on Linux and OSx as far as I remember, more work would be necessary for Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those wondering how to :
https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding

There's an example using openGL to render a flutter app

Answer (score 3):

### Run a Flutter project in Desktop

*Step 1:*
For Flutter to run on Desktop, we must be on the master channel, with the latest release. So run from `cmd`,

```
flutter channel master
```

and

```
flutter upgrade
```

*Step 2:*
Then we have to enable flutter desktop support.

```
set ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true
```

*Step 3:*
Then clone [this repo](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git) and `cd` example directory.

*Step 4:*
Then replace the `lib` folder inside the example directory with our existing code, and replace the pubspec.yaml file, with our existing one.

*Step 5:*
Then run from terminal

```
flutter packages get
```

and

```
flutter run
```

You can find more info [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link out

https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding

Still not stable but does a good job of rendering flutter apps on desktop

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I found useful, it is currently in alpha version but does the job by enabling us to develop Mac and Windows apps in Flutter : 
https://feather-apps.com/

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know the current state(2021), here is the [startup project](https://github.com/Tokenyet/flutter_desktop_ci_example) to help you test It for MacOS, Linux, Windows. The project heavily modified from [official ci](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml) to build cross-platform easily. You might want to check the [ci.yml](https://github.com/Tokenyet/flutter_desktop_ci_example/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml) If you want to build on certain platform without github-action.

In additional, [go-flutter](https://hover.drakirus.com/) is also a valid option, that used [go-lang](https://golang.org/) and **openGL** to achieve cross-platform features.

If you want to know the difference between [official](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) and [go-flutter](https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter), here is [the issue](https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter/issues/191) about the details.