# Can we create windows(pc) app with the help of flutter / dart?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am just a beginner and started to learn about flutter.
I will like to know that can we create windows pc applications with the help of flutter/dart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build flutter app for desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156511/build-flutter-app-for-desktops)

Answer (score 1):

you can reference this to create app for windows https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter 
go-flutter-desktop has more than 3000 star in github. 
I contribute to plugin and also use it to build my windows app.

example is here https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/examples

How does this compare to the "official" flutter desktop? https://github.com/go-flutter-desktop/go-flutter/issues/191

You can also reference this repo too , Build beautiful desktop apps with flutter and rust https://github.com/flutter-rs/flutter-rs

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can! Here is a simple article to introduce you to web dev in Flutter

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0

Comment: That post is already out of date in several respects. The official documentation at http://flutter.dev/desktop is a better place to point people, as it is updated as the project evolves.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has early stage support for desktop; see http://flutter.dev/desktop for an overview of the current status.

Since `flutter create` doesn't support desktop yet, the easiest place to start is with the [flutter-desktop-embedding](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) example.